# Consolidate duplicate rows based on subgrouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of temporal values in which there exist repeated values in groupings, but I want to remove all but one for each grouping and maintain the order (can't just say the distinct values).

If the sequence of rows was as such in order

```
+------+-----+
| time | col |
+------+-----+
| 1    | A   |
| 2    | A   |
| 3    | A   |
| 4    | B   |
| 5    | B   |
| 6    | B   |
| 7    | C   |
| 8    | D   |
| 9    | E   |
| 10   | A   |
| 11   | A   |
| 12   | B   |
+------+-----+
```

Then it should be resulted as

```
+-----+
| col |
+-----+
| A   |
| B   |
| C   |
| D   |
| E   |
| A   |
| B   |
+-----+
```

Is there a way to do this without a cursor? How I would do it in not SQL would be to iterate over the list and say if the current index matches the previous index, then pop it.

Comment: You should show your data in tabular form, where rows are represented as *rows*.  In addition, you should show the column that specifies the ordering of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The rows you want to remove depend on the ordering, specifically adjacent identical values are being removed.

In order to have an ordering, the data needs a column that specifies it.  Let me assume you have one.

If so, this is easily handled with `lag()`:

```
select col
from (select t.*, lag(col) over (order by orderingcol) as prev_col
      from t
     ) t
where prev_col <> col or prev_col is null;
```